# Disabling Global for Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to turn off the Global setting (as it is set default to be used on .NET) as what I am trying to do only needs to change the first part of a string, however there is the the chance that it will occur twice in the string, for example I wish for

> C00000WPF0000SAND

to only change the first instance of 0's.

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(text, "^[a-z]+00+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
    text = Regex.Replace(text, "0{1,}", "00*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

This is how I am currently doing it, however this seems to take every single instance of the "00+" and change it but this messes things up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify a match limit; the documentation for `Regex.Replace(string, string, RegexOptions)` specifically states that it replaces all instances of the found pattern.  There is no static overload of `Regex.Replace` that takes both a match limit and regex options, so you will have to construct a Regex object and then use the `Replace(string, string, int)` overload.  Try this:

```
text = new Regex("0{1,}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Replace(text, "00*", 1);
```

Comment: Kotlin documentation specifically stating that it replaces all instances: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/replace.html

Answer (score 2):

You could alter your regex slightly so that it matches the intended pattern and only replaces the first set of zeroes. That also helps cut out the `IsMatch` call.

The pattern you can use is: `(?<=^[a-z]+)00+`

This pattern is similar to your first one, except it uses a look-behind, `(?<=^[a-z]+)`, to ensure that the match occurs as intended at the beginning of the string with letters. The usage of a look-behind will match, but not consume, so the replace won't affect that portion of the string.

```
string text = "C00000WPF0000SAND";
text = Regex.Replace(text, "(?<=^[a-z]+)00+", "00*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, "(?i)^([a-z]+)00+", "${1}00*");
```

In which case you don't need the `if` at all.